# How to find out availability calendar meeting in office 365 using ews?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exchangewebservices

Hi,
i need to get particular user availability timing in office 365, but i am getting this error while i am accessing the calendar events "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it", i am giving my code below,any one help me to resolve this error.

```
        string stat = "06/18/2016 11:00:00 AM";
        string end = "06/18/2016 2:00:00 PM";

        DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(stat);
        DateTime endt = Convert.ToDateTime(end);

        string mailBox = "XXXXXXXX@XXXX.com";

        ExchangeService esvc = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        esvc.Credentials = new WebCredentials("XXXXXXXXX@XXXXXX.com", "XXXXX", "XXXX.com");
        esvc.Url = new Uri("https://XXXXXX.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");

        FolderId shareFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "Calendar");
        // The following line throws an exception.
        CalendarFolder.Bind(esvc, shareFolderId);


        FolderId parkplatzCalendarId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, mailBox);

        CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(esvc, parkplatzCalendarId);

        CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(start, endt, int.MaxValue);

        cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.Duration, AppointmentSchema.LastModifiedName, AppointmentSchema.Organizer, AppointmentSchema.Categories);

        FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, on which line of code do you get that exception?

Comment: Maybe you are not supplying the *primary SMTP address* of the user, but an alias?

Comment: thanks for replay Speedbrid, i am getting this error 10th line of my code "  CalendarFolder.Bind(esvc, shareFolderId); "

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "Calendar" does not make sense when you create the `FolderId`:

```
FolderId shareFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "Calendar");
```

Instead you should replace "Calendar" with a mailbox object for the user:

```
FolderId shareFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox("user@domain.com"));
```